# Setting parameters on context in AsyncItemProcessor

Tags: spring-batch

I wrote a code which:

1. loops on a delimited file holding customer id list.
2. per customer get list of products using - AsyncItemProcessor.
3. Update counters.

How can I update the counters while the item processor is async?

```java
public class BulkExportItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String,String>  
{
    @Inject
    public IProductRepository repository;
    
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String process(String customerIds) {

        String[] customerIdsList = customerIds.split(",");

        int processRecordsIncrement = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < customerIdsList.length; i++) {

            String customerId = customerIdsList[i];
            List<IProductDTO> products = repository.getProducts(customerId, null);
            
            for(IProductDTO product:products) {
                    
                processRecordsIncrement++;
                System.out.println("\n handling product: " + product.getProductId() + " of customer: " + customerId);

            }
        }
            
        int processedRecords = stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getInt("PROCESSED_RECORDS");
        processedRecords+=processRecordsIncrement;
        stepExecution.getExecutionContext(). putInt("PROCESSED_RECORDS", processedRecords);
            
        int processedCustomers = stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getInt("PROCESSED_CUST");
        processedCustomers+=customerIdsList.length;
            stepExecution.getExecutionContext().putInt("PROCESSED_CUST", processedCustomers);
        return  customerIds;
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ExportBatchConfiguration 
{
    @Inject
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Inject
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<String> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<String>()
                .name("voltItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("Customers.csv"))
                .build();
    }
    
   @Bean
   public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("ProductExportJob")
                                .start(exportStep())
                                .listener()
                                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step exportStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("ProductExportJob")
                .<String, String>chunk(3)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(asyncItemProcessor())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<String,String> asyncItemProcessor(){
        AsyncItemProcessor<String, String> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<String, String>();
        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate((ItemProcessor) new BulkExportItemProcessor());
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(getAsyncExecutor());
        return (ItemProcessor) asyncItemProcessor;
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncExecutor-");
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Comment: My question reffers to updating context parameter by few Asyn Item processors simultanisly and avoid overriding one thread overriding other thread set value.

Answer (score 0):

The execution context is a mutable shared state between the different threads of your async item processor. So you need to make sure the section that updates it is thread safe.